# Gateway in star topology

Tags: networking, switch, gateway

Imagine a network consisting of three computers all of which connecting to a switch. And we need to manually fill routing table in one of them.

The gateway column in routing table must contain the same information as the Next hop. But there is no next hop; all packets directly go between computers without any mediation (they actually go throught the switch, but it has no IP-address).

So what is the correct value for the gateway in the routing table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **none**, you don't need a gateway in order that the machines can communicate. In fact you don't even need routing, or a routing table.

If all the computers are in the same subnet, which they must, they don't need a gateway to communicate. A gateway is needed only when ou want to communicate with a machine that is on another network. Like I've said before they don't even need routing.

I recommend you read a tutorial or a book about IP. [This](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/workingwithipaddresses/l/blip.htm) can be an option.

Comment: PS: sory I can't give a better explanation about this but I don't have the proper time. The tutorial I pointed to can help but maybe someone can give a more detailed explanation. Anyway I really recommend you study a little bit about IP since I think you're missing some background.

Comment: But how 'none' will look in the routing table? (if I print it, for example)

Comment: @Lescott In fact you don't even need a routing table. Routing is done between multiple networks. If you don't have multiple networks you don't need routing.

Comment: okay, imagine one more network interface, wlan0 for example with an internet access. Now we need a routing table :) So how `none` will look in the table?

Comment: @Lescott It will specify the interface. The routing interface will effectively say something like `192.168.0.0/16 is available on eth0`. The system then knows that everything on the `192.168.0.0/16` network goes out `eth0`. This is the same on all the theoretical computers (minus the fact that `eth0` might actually be named differently, but it's all the same concept)

Comment: @Lescott imagine your "internal" network is `192.168.1.0` and `wlan` is connected to other network. The default gateway should be the IP address of the ethernet interface in the computer that have the `wlan`, like `192.168.1.10`, and the routing table will look something like `0.0.0.0    192.168.1.10   0.0.0.0` (`network   next_hop   netmask`).

Answer (score 1):

In most systems, for a route in a routing table, you either set an interface or give a next hop (or both).

In the case where only an interface is given, the packet will be sent directly to the destination host's MAC address through that interface (i.e. packets for hosts within the same subnet).

If a next hop is given, then the packet will be sent to the MAC address corresponding to that IP and the port used to send this packet is figured out using an interface route mentioned above.

In systems where you're not allowed to supply a port for the destination, you can probably use an IP address bound to the port to identify the port. For example:

Your computer's IP 10.0.0.2 on a /24 subnet. Your routing table should look like

```
IP         Mask Next hop
10.0.0.0   /24  10.0.0.2 (meaning the NIC 10.0.0.2 is connected to)
10.0.0.2   /32  127.0.0.1 (meaning the loop back interface)
10.0.0.255 /32  10.0.0.2
```